# Variable in link of image

Tags: react-native, expo

I am making expo app and I have a database, where is all information about articels. I am displaying all informations and all was ok until that moment when i wanted to display variable in link of image. I have tried to use it with require, source, uri, but it did not work. How i can display variable in link of image. Help me please.

```html
   <Image
               source={{uri:rowData.article_image}}
              
             />
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing image styling, image won't show if you don't set `width` and `height`

```
<Image
  style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
  source={{uri:rowData.article_image}}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I do not know what component you use for `<Image />` here it is an url directly applied to an image:

```
<img src={rowData.article_image} />
```

Comment: i said that i am using expo ! There is no img, only <Image />

Answer (score 0):

Add a path from where you are getting the image.
You can append like this in render

```
let article_image
article_image = `/assets/uploads/${this.state.article_image}`;
```

And in return

```
<img src={article_image} className="img-responsive" alt="Some Fancy Example 
Image" />
```

Comment: i said that i am using expo ! There is no img, only <Image />

Answer (score 0):

React Native and Expo purposely prevent you from using variables or anything other than a static non-changing string when requiring a file (including Images, Sound, and other Javascript files) no matter how you require it (through source, require, or uri).

Also read this comment on the same page for a better explanation: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2481#issuecomment-137982505

The following solution comes from the Expo documentation (https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/react-native/images/):

```
// GOOD
<Image source={require('./my-icon.png')} />;

// BAD
var icon = this.props.active ? 'my-icon-active' : 'my-icon-inactive';
<Image source={require('./' + icon + '.png')} />;

// GOOD
var icon = this.props.active
    ? require('./my-icon-active.png')
    : require('./my-icon-inactive.png');
<Image source={icon} />;
```

That last good section is the only way you can do it. A simple if statement. If `this.props.active === true` then the first require is used, if false, then the second is used.